# Intel XDK - how to install app on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: deployment, windows-phone, intel-xdk, windows-10-mobile

I have create an app with Intel XDK and it works perfectly on Android and Ios. I am now attempting to test it on a Windows Device and then send it to the Windows Store.
Building the app in Intel XDK, it creates the .appxupload and a test folder with the .appx file.
My question is how do I get it on the damn phone? I have tried everything.

The last thing i tried was using WinAppDeployCmd but it is giving me the error "The package must be digitally signed for signature validation". I thought Intel XDK did everything! How do I sign it (if this is what I really need to do)?